# use a function parameter as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<unsigned int size>
struct Vec {
    Vec() = default;
};

auto build_vec(unsigned int size) {
    return Vec<size>();
}

int main() {
    auto vec = build_vec(5);
    return 0;
}
```

This program doesn't compile as `non-type template argument is not a constant expression`. Basically, the `size` parameter sent into `build_vec` is not known to the compiler during compilation type.

Then I wonder, can I add some keyword to force `size` to be evaluated during compile time thus struct `Vec` can be built through a function?

Comment: Types are decided at compile-time and can't depend on runtime information. What are the possible values of `size`? There's a workaround if there's only a few of them, but it doesn't scale.

Comment: `template <unsigned int size>auto build_vec()`, `auto vec = build_vec<5>();`?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi No, just an dummy example. I'm looking for a way to use function parameter as template parameter.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thought about that already. But my code base constrains me that it has to be a function parameter, not template parameter.

Comment: This is not possible. The `size` of `template<unsigned int size> struct Vec` has to be given at compile time. The value of a function argument is not known at compile-time. If it has to be a function argument then you cannot use a template parameter to achieve this. (That's why there are two containers in the standard library for this: `std::array` vs. `std::vector`.)

Comment: `template <unsigned int size>auto build_vec(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, size>)` to have function parameter :)

Comment: @Jarod42 could you elaborate?

Comment: See nhatnq's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. A functions parameter is not known at compile time. The common way to signal that `size` must be known at compile time is to make the function a template and `size` a template parameter:

```
template<unsigned int size>
struct Vec {
    Vec() = default;
};

template <unsigned int size>
auto build_vec() {
    return Vec<size>();
}

int main() {
    auto vec = build_vec<5>();
}
```

Though, now it should be obvious that the function does not help to turn a runtime value into a compile time value. In general thats not possible, unless you implement such mapping manually. You don't need `build_vec` because the caller can use `auto vec = Vec<size>();` directly.

Comment: Yeah, but this is not according to the [OPs requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968404/use-a-function-parameter-as-template-parameter#comment120134393_67968404) that the size has to be a function argument...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat my plan was to explain that thats not possible, but somehow I forget to answer that ;)

Comment: A `switch()` could achieve this. But it doesn't scale well (as already pointed out by [@HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968404/use-a-function-parameter-as-template-parameter#comment120134332_67968404).) It would only work when only a few possible values are expected which are all known at compile time...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat What I had in mind is a "templated switch" that doesn't require you to write boilerplate. But would still generate boilerplate instantiations under the hood.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this would lead to extreme code bloat, due to all the instantiations that arent actually used, no? Anyhow, I'd love to see an answer

Comment: fwiw, I realized that I slightly misinterpreted the question, and this answer is merely stating the obvious but can be considered incomplete. I'll leave it up until a real answer is posted or I can fix it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yep, that's why I'm waiting for OP to confirm that the range of valid values is small before making an answer. The basic idea is to use `std::integral_sequence` to generate an array of function pointers, then call i-th function.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat return type would have to depend on runtime function argument, and that's not possible.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Yeah, you would have to declare the vector variable inside of the template, and only use it inside. The exact interface OP asked for is impossible.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n8xrGPxns) small example clang sees through the whole thing, and doesn't instantiate anything. GCC fails to do that. If I increase the range from 10 to 100, both of them give up and do all the generations. It's a bit of hit or miss.

Answer (score 1):

It does NOT fit your expectation completely but rely on boost hana approach we may have similar one. Below is an example using variable template

```
#include <iostream>

template<unsigned int size>
struct Vec {
    Vec() = default;
    ~Vec() {std::cout << size << '\n';}
};


template <unsigned int i>
constexpr std::integral_constant<unsigned int, i> uint_c{};

template <unsigned int i>
auto build_vec(std::integral_constant<unsigned int, i>) {
    return Vec<i>();
}

int main() {
    const size_t n = 5;
    auto vec = build_vec(uint_c<n>);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> my code base constrains me that it has to be a function parameter, not template parameter.

That's not possible. Return type of a function cannot be dependent on runtime values. Your options are:

1. Make the template argument of `Vec` a runtime value as well.
2. If the possible set of runtime values are small, you may generate all the code needed at compile time and use a few runtime branches to determine what to use. The return type cannot depend on this, so you can return a type-erased object (`std::any`, etc), have the `Vec` class derive from some base class, or not return the object. Don't do this if the range is too large. It may [generate](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n8xrGPxns) lots of code-bloat:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

template <unsigned size>
struct Vec {
  Vec() = default;
  void use_value() { std::printf("My constexpr value is %u\n", size); }
};

template <unsigned ct_val>
void build_vec_impl_impl() {
  Vec<ct_val> cant_return;
  cant_return.use_value();
}

template <unsigned... vals>
void build_vec_impl(std::integer_sequence<unsigned, vals...>, unsigned rt_val) {
  using fp_builder = void (*)();

  constexpr fp_builder builders[]{build_vec_impl_impl<vals>...};
  builders[rt_val]();
}

template <unsigned max>
void build_vec(unsigned const rt_val) {
  using seq = std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, max + 1>;
  build_vec_impl(seq{}, rt_val);
}

int main() {
  auto constexpr max = 10;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < max; ++i) build_vec<max>(i);
}
```

<sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup>3. Use a dynamic language like Python where return type may depend on runtime values</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: Instead of `std::any`, I would prefer `std::variant<Vec<0>, .., Vec<N>>`.